# I am getting segmentation fault ( core dumped ) when I am running the program

Tags: c

`pos.dat` file contains:

```
1 2 4
1 2 3
1 2 1
1 2 3
```

I'm getting a `segmentation fault` when I run the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE  *fp;
    int line = 4, i = 1;
    float *x, *y, *z;
    fp = fopen("pos.dat", "r");
    while (i <= line) {
        fscanf(fp, "%f%f%f", &*x, &*y, &*z);
        printf(fp, "%f\t%f\t%f\n", *x, *y, *z);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers here? When you create a pointer without initializing it to some value, it points to some random location in memory that probably isn't allocated for your program to use. Therefore, trying to write something to that location causes undefined behavior and a segfault in this case. Either allocate some memory and assign the address to your pointer or not use pointers in the first place. That said, there's probably a good duplicate somewhere out there.

Answer (score 6):

`float *x;` declares a `float` pointer. When you then try to use it, `scanf()` will attempt to dereference the pointer without it having been initialized first with a valid address.

What you want to do instead is declare `float`s, not `float` pointers:

```
float x, y, z;
...
fscanf(fp,"%f%f%f", &x, &y, &z);
...
printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", x, y, z);
```

Comment: `&*x you are dereferencing the pointer without having initialized it first with a valid address.` That is strictly speaking not true. The adress-of operator and the dereference operator cancel each other out, so the pointer itself is passed (by value copy) to scanf. But scanf will dereference the uninitialized pointer -> UB.